# Adding multiple lines of collection text to an email

Tags: c#, email, blueprism, rpa

I currently have a collection that can have between 2-4 rows and I am trying to attach these rows to an email body.

However, when I am using the 'Email Notifications' Business Object and the 'Notifications-Send Email' action, it only enters the first row and ignores the rest.

I have attached screenshots below of my process

How can I make it so it enters all rows in the email? If there is a code stage way possible I am open to that also

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add this collection to the email you need to first change it to string, that can be added to email. The way you've built it, you're only adding a value from one cell - the one from that column and current row.

There is no official Utility action that can change collection to text. Closest one I can find is action "Get Collection as CSV" from object "Utility - Strings", but the output is not user friendly.

The other way is to loop through collection [Emails Not Sent] and join the data from collection to a text data item. Afterwards you can use that data item in the email that you're sending.

Finally, I'd like to suggest for you, to send emails using HTML mode. There are numerous advantages to that - you can use html formatting, hyperlinks, tables. It is be also pretty straightforward to create an action, that will output a nicely looking html table ready to be added to body of the email you're sending.

Comment: So, you're suggesting to loop the values received into a data item instead of a collection and adding that in instead?